# Why can I assign null to an Option?

Tags: scala

The following are valid statements in Scala:

```
scala> var x: Option[Int] = Some(3)
x: Option[Int] = Some(3)

scala> var x: Option[Int] = None
x: Option[Int] = None
```

The following is invalid:

```
scala> var x: Option[Int] = 3
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(3)
 required: Option[Int]
       var x: Option[Int] = 3
```

So far these examples make sense to me; a value of type Option[T] can be either of type Some[T] or None, so the compiler prevents you from assigning a value which is of neither type.

However, the Scala compiler appears to accept this:

```
scala> val x: Option[Int] = null
x: Option[Int] = null
```

If I then try to do a pattern match on the option (e.g. as below), I'll get failures I didn't expect - why doesn't the compiler protect me from this by rejecting the assignment of null?

```
x match {
  case Some(y) => println("Number: ", y)
  case None => println("No number")
}
```

Comment: Any reference can be null; it's just an unfortunate consequence of running on the JVM.

Comment: Thanks Christopher! I just read [this article](http://www.naildrivin5.com/blog/2010/07/30/in-offense-of-scala-option.html) which says "Of course, none of this does save you from null, because Scala is perfectly happy to assign null to anything. It kinda makes the whole thing seem a bit pointless."

It is a bit disappointing; I was going on the assumption that the Option (Some/None) matching pattern was complete, but actually to be complete I guess you would need to match Some / None / null, and have a further check on the value you get from Some.

Comment: On further reading around, I think I understand a little better. Option is more about conveying the programmer's _intent_, that a certain method might return a value or not. If the code being called is well behaved, the caller doesn't need to deal with null explicitly, because the caller doesn't expect it. As mentioned [here](http://james-iry.blogspot.jp/2010/08/why-scalas-and-haskells-types-will-save.html), "the experience that all the Scala developers I know have is that NPE is mostly only a problem when dealing with existing Java libraries because Scala programmers and libraries avoid it."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the [Scala class hierarchy](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/128), you'll see that all classes deriving from `AnyRef` are super classes of `Null`, and any such super class can be assigned the value `null`. Since `Option` is one such class, you can assign `Null` to it.

Note that both `Some` and `None.type` (that is, the singleton type of the `None` object) are super classes of `Null`, so `null` is a valid value for either one.

You cannot assign `3` to `Option` because `3` is not a value of a sub class of `Option` (evidently).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question you probably intended to ask goes something like this:

Idiomatic Scala will never use `null`.  Null references exist purely for interoperability with Java and other JVM languages.  If you see `null` in Scala code it should immediately attract scrutiny. You would never use `null` by mistake so a compiler warning is unnecessary.  As noted in Daniel Sobral's answer and the comments the compiler cannot provide protection against `null`.